# How can you deal with circular references when mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

Take this database for example

**Employee**

- id - int (PK)
- name - varchar

**Salary**

- id - int (PK)
- employee_id - int (FK)
- amount - float

Entity Framework will generate models similar to these:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Salaries = new HashSet<Salary>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Salary
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    public float amount  { get; set; }
    public Employee employee { get; set; }
}
```

The Emplyee references a list of his Salaries while each Salary points to which employee he owns. This results in a circular reference problem.

I follow a repository pattern and use AutoMapper to transfer Employee to EmployeeDTO and Salary to SalaryDTO. I want those DTOs to keep infomation of it's children relationships. However, I dont want to do this recursively. I COULD do something like.

```
public partial class EmployeeDTO
{
    public EmployeeDTO()
    {
        this.Salaries = new HashSet<SalaryChildDTO>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public partial class SalaryChildDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public float amount  { get; set; }
}
```

But this would become a maintenance nightmare.

How can I tell AutoMapper to only map a single decendant, or acheive a similar goal?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up going the DTO - ChildDTO route because I found an easy to manage way of doing it.

```
public partial class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SalaryChildDTO> Salaries { get; set; } //Notice the Virtual
}

public partial class EmployeeChildDTO : EmployeeDTO
{
    [IgnoreMap] //MAGIC!
    public override IEnumerable<SalaryChildDTO> Salaries { get; set; } //Override! :o
}

public partial class SalaryDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int employe_id { get; set; }
    public float amount  { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeChildDTO Employee { get; set; } //Notice the Virtual once again
}

public partial class SalaryChildDTO : SalaryDTO
{
    [IgnoreMap] //MAGIC!
    public override EmployeeChildDTO Employee { get; set; } //Override! :o
}
```

That way, the only database changes that affects the child DTOs are FKs!

I could have done it the other way arround (EmployeeDTO extends EmployeeChildDTO) and avoid Overrides and Virtuals and IgnoreMaps but I wanted to keep the core DTO as the base class.

Comment: How has this worked out in long term? Has it been OK in terms of maintenance?

Comment: @Korijn For other reasons, I ended up not using this at all (or reverting after a while). I will unmark this answer since I cannot give a follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why this would be a maintenance nightmare. I've been doing the same thing for a while now and it's working fine for me. One thing to note though is that you still want the employee ID inside the `SalaryChildDTO` class.

Comment: Because it doubles the amount of classes you have to manually change when you want to add / modify the model / database and the amount of triples the amount of Maps I need to configure.

Comment: That is true. But it's something you cannot avoid if you want to separate your domain model from the rest of your application. If the number of domain objects in your project isn't in the 100's, then it's totally okay to create a DTO or even multiple DTO's that are relevant to each business operation you have. And AutoMapper should make your life much easier than having to do all the mapping plumbing yourself. Having to maintain changes in your domain and DTO layers is far better than having to solve other issues resulting from using your domain layer in your UI layer or the service layer.

Comment: What I have a hard time accepting is that AutoMapper doesn't actually make my life easier in terms of how many changes I have to apply if I do a change in the domain object. Instead of making a child class for every DTO in the project, I could just do manual mapping and it would result in pretty much the same amount of work.... That's why, in my head, there MUST be another way.... I just dont feel like it's right...

Comment: No, it's still not the same amount of work. In most cases, your DTO's will look very much like your domain objects. AutoMapper is smart enough to map properties that are named similarly, but is also powerful enough to allow you to configure the mapping between properties when that's not the case.

Comment: I mean, if you manually map EF POCOs to DTOs, you wouldnt need to make "ChildDTOs" so you just replace the time to write a Child DTO by writing manual mapping