# How to map many-to-many relationship with Automapper and EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, automapper

I am using Automapper in order to be able to map my Entities to DTOs. Some of my entities are in many-to-many relationship and when I perform the mapping I get stack overflow error:

[image]

This is my entity and corresponding entity dto:

```
public partial class Group
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Group()
        {
            Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2147483647)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Tag
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Tag()
        {
            Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2147483647)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, this is **many to many** relationship between **Groups** and **Tags**.

My DTOs look like this:

```
public class GroupDto
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TagDto> Tags { get; set; }
        public ICollection<long> TagIds { get; set; }
    }

public class TagDto
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GroupDto> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping configuration looks like this:

```
CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>();
CreateMap<GroupDto, Group>();

CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>();
CreateMap<TagDto, Tag>();
```

The exception gets fired from here:

```
var groupEntity = this._unitOfWork.GroupRepository.GetGroups().FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);

            if (groupEntity == null)
                return null;

             var groupAsDto = this._mapper.Map<Group, GroupDto>(groupEntity);
```

How can I avoid this and get a proper DTO from the Entity? I observed the Entity returned by the repository and it is as expected.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible. You can familiarize with workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763042/how-to-avoid-circular-references-with-automapper ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941180/how-can-you-deal-with-circular-references-when-mapping

Comment: I can not believe this is not possible. This is quite a common scenario.

Comment: Maybe this workaround satisfy you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper (see accepted answer)