# How to reomove cirular refernce when automapped domain classes and custom model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper-5

I am using autommapper to convert domain class to custom Model in asp.net, the problem is that automapper creates circular 
refernces with child objects,how can i remove circular refernces?

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.CreateMap<Appointment, AppointmentModel>()
                             //.ForMember(x => x.Profile.Appointments, opt => opt.Ignore())

                             //.ForPath(m => m.User.Profile, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             // .ForPath(m => m.User.Appointments, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //  .ForPath(m => m.User.Appointments1, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //   .ForPath(m => m.User.Appointments2, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //     .ForPath(m => m.User.City, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //       .ForPath(m => m.User.Claims, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //       .ForPath(m => m.User.Employee, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //       .ForPath(m => m.User.Logins, opt => opt.Ignore())
                             //       .ForPath(m => m.User.Physician, opt => opt.Ignore())

                             .ForMember(dest => dest.Profile,
                                    opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src?.Profile))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.DoctorUser,
                                    opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src?.User1))
                             .ForMember(dest => dest.User,
                                    opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src?.User));

                    });
                    IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();

                    return iMapper.Map<List<Appointment>, List<AppointmentModel>>(model?.ToList());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you deal with circular references when mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941180/how-can-you-deal-with-circular-references-when-mapping)

Comment: Can i use MaxDepth() and PreserveReferences() to resolve circular refernece.

Comment: That's handled by default in newer versions.